# SQL Modify Column name Case changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with column name as Forgotpassword.
I am facing issues in the c# code because the model is named as ForgotPassword. (P is in caps)

I want to rename the Column name from Forgotpassword to ForgotPassword.
Data is already available in this column in the table.

Is there any way to alter columns based on sensitiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
EXEC sp_rename 't.Forgotpassword', 'ForgotPassword', 'COLUMN';
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f487fb4f4644b8a01d60d00eeacebdb).